# Error nested routing

Tags: angular, url-routing, lazy-loading, angular6

I updated latest @angular/cli version (v6), and I modularize all routes in routing-module. Like that:

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    loadChildren: './components/blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
  }
```

But when start the app, I get that error:
[image]

Some have any idea to fix that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In agular router array must be given values highest to lowest priority  first change it like this always provide values in Array **first URL** then **empty path** and then **Wild Card** ** . problem maybe in code show that also.

```
 {
    path: 'blog',
    loadChildren: './components/blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
  },
 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I changed my code here, but the problem still persisted, the problem is solved only with AOT.... Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in your routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home',  //set default load module here
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
    path: 'home', 
    loadChildren: './components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
},
{
    path: 'blog', 
    loadChildren: './components/blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
}];
```

Comment: Great! I tried this code but the problem still persisted, the problem is solved only with AOT.... Thanks again!!